# Aligning equations in 3 columns

Tags: math-mode, align

I want to align two equations in 3 columns (so empty space in the middle). How do I align another equation in the next column with the empty space?

```
\begin{align*}
a&=144 & b&=51666 \\
& c&=d &
\end{align*}
```

Above is the faulty code. I thought that if I left empty ampersands, the second ampersand, which is where I want the alignment to be, would ignore the first alignment point and skip to the second one. There's clearly something wrong with the logic but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each ampersand `&` provides a `r`ight-and-`l`eft alignment around it. Here's what you're looking for in your `align` construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a &= 144 &   &    & b &= 51666 \\
    &      & c &= d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```